# In a Spring 3.0 GET request, what's the difference between a @PathVariable and a @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In an example such as the following, what's the difference between a `@PathVariable` and a `@RequestParam`?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/portfolio/{portfolioIdPath}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String portfolio(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, 
@PathVariable long portfolioIdPath, @RequestParam long portfolioIdRequest)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**@RequestParam** binds a request parameter to a parameter in your method.  In your example, the value of the parameter named "portfolioIdRequest" in the GET request will be passed as the "portfolioIdRequest" argument to your method.  A more concrete example - if the request URL is

```
http://hostname/portfolio/123?portfolioIdRequest=456
```

then the value of the parameter "portfolioIdRequest" will be "456".

*More info here*: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

**@PathVariable** similarly binds the value of the URI template variable "portfolioIdPath" to the method parameter "portfolioIdPath".  For example, if your URI is

```
/portfolio/123
```

then the value of "portfolioIdPath" method parameter will be "123".

*More info here*: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Answer (score 2):

@RequestParam identifies the HTTP GET or POST parameter which is sent by the client(user), And @RequestMapping extracts a  segment of URL which varies from request to request:

```
http://host/?var=1
```

In the above URL *"var"* is a requestparam.

```
http://host/registration/{which}
```

and above URL's *{which}* is a request mapping. You could call your service like :

```
http://host/registration/user
```

OR like

```
http://host/registration/firm
```

In your application you can access the value of *{which}* (In first case which="user" and in second which="firm".

Answer (score 0):

It depends the way you want to handle your request

```
@RequestParam example
(request)http://something.com/owner?ownerId=1234

@PathVariable example
(request) http://something.com/owner/1234
(in tour code) /owner/{ownerId}
```