# @RequestMapping with parameter in the middle of path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, url, spring-mvc

Let's say I'm displaying a schedule for academic group with id = 1 at the following URL: `http://localhost:8222/schedule?groupId=1`.

At this page I have buttons for deleting specific lessons from the schedule. Button's `action` attribute in JSP has the following value: `"schedule?${pageContext.request.queryString}/delete/${lessons[count].id}"`, so clicking the "Delete" button near the lesson with id = 1 causes the redirect to this URL: `http://localhost:8222/schedule?groupId=1/delete/1`.

What I want to do is create a method that is mapped to this URL, which performs deletion and redirects to the page with schedule for currently selected group: `http://localhost:8222/schedule?groupId=1`. Here's what I've tried to do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule?groupId={groupId}/delete/{lessonId}")
public String deleteLesson(@PathVariable("lessonId") Integer lessonId, @PathVariable("groupId") Integer groupId) {
    lessonRepository.delete(lessonId);
    return "redirect:/schedule?groupId=" + groupId;
}
```

But that doesn't work, this method is never called. How do I write this method properly for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: No, that URL doesn't make any sense. The query string is something that comes at the end, not in the middle. Create something more restful like `/schedule/1/lesson/1` and send a DELETE request to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the use of `groupId` like this `?groupId`, `groupId` becomes a parameter and the later part of the URL becomes its value. so if you dont want to change the existing URL patterns your request handling method should be like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule")
public String deleteLesson(@RequestParam("groupId") String restOfTheUrl) {

  log.info(restOfTheUrl);
  // your code
}
```

After logging it you should see, for example:

```
 1/delete/2
```

Now you have to parse it for having `groupId` and lesson `id` for deletion.

But if you want to handle it in your way, your code should be like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/schedule/groupId/{groupId}/delete/{lessonId}") // convert you request param to path varriable
 public String deleteLesson(@PathVariable("lessonId") Integer lessonId, @PathVariable("groupId") Integer groupId) {
    lessonRepository.delete(lessonId);
    return "redirect:/schedule?groupId=" + groupId;
 }
```

To learn more:

- [difference between a @PathVariable and a @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073970/in-a-spring-3-0-get-request-whats-the-difference-between-a-pathvariable-and-a)